# Libgdx Touch Event Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, libgdx, garbage-collection, touch

In my libgdx android project, I see log of "I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP/DOWN" for any screen touch and about 0.01 mb increment in heap usage. I touch absolutely no object on screen but empty areas.

- Is it possible to turn off touch event log?
- The memory usage increment caused by touch event may lead garbage collection eventually. What would be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Memory allocation is not the same as a memory leak. A memory leak is memory that will not be cleared by a GC because of remaining references or unmanaged memory.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work.